# DirectX11 drawing simple triangle

Tags: directx, directx-11

I tried to draw a simple triangle using DXUT11, but I can't see the triangle in my window.
I worked hard but still can't find out where the problem is   -_-

I had checked every returned value of the D3D functions, and they all returned S_OK.
I can see my window show up and the background color is the color I set to clear the window,
so it seems the d3d device was created currectly and the back buffer was rendered to the window, 
but WHERE IS THE YELLOW TRIANGLE ?
T_T...............

my code is as follows:(to simplify the problem, I have deleted all the checking S_OK sentence)

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#define DXUT_AUTOLIB
#include <DXUT.h>
#include <DXUTres.h>
#include <D3DX11.h>
#include <xnamath.h>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib,"d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"dxut.lib")


ID3D10Blob * g_pVertexShaderBuffer = 0;
ID3D10Blob * g_pPixelShaderBuffer = 0;
ID3D11VertexShader * g_pVertexShader = 0;
ID3D11PixelShader * g_pPixelShader = 0;
ID3D11InputLayout * g_pInputLayout = 0;

ID3D11Buffer * g_pVertexBuffer = 0;
ID3D11Buffer * g_pIndexBuffer = 0;

struct Vertex
{
XMFLOAT3 pos;
};


bool CALLBACK IsD3D11DeviceAcceptable( const CD3D11EnumAdapterInfo *AdapterInfo, UINT Output, const CD3D11EnumDeviceInfo *DeviceInfo,
                       DXGI_FORMAT BackBufferFormat, bool bWindowed, void* pUserContext )
{
    return true;
}

HRESULT CALLBACK onDeviceCreated( ID3D11Device* pd3dDevice, const DXGI_SURFACE_DESC* pBackBufferSurfaceDesc, void* pUserContext )
{
    ID3D11DeviceContext * pd3dImmediateContext = DXUTGetD3D11DeviceContext();
    ID3D10Blob * err = NULL;
    D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"Tutorial03.fx",0,0,"VS","vs_4_0",D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG|D3DCOMPILE_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION,0,0,&g_pVertexShaderBuffer,&err,0);
    D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"Tutorial03.fx",0,0,"PS","ps_4_0",D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG|D3DCOMPILE_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION,0,0,&g_pPixelShaderBuffer,&err,0);

    HRESULT res = 0;
    res = pd3dDevice->CreateVertexShader(g_pVertexShaderBuffer->GetBufferPointer(),g_pVertexShaderBuffer->GetBufferSize(),NULL,&g_pVertexShader);
    res = pd3dDevice->CreatePixelShader(g_pPixelShaderBuffer->GetBufferPointer(),g_pPixelShaderBuffer->GetBufferSize(),NULL,&g_pPixelShader);

    pd3dImmediateContext->VSSetShader(g_pVertexShader,0,0);
    pd3dImmediateContext->PSSetShader(g_pPixelShader,0,0);


    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inputElement[]=
    {
    {"POSITION",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,0,0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0}
    };

    int numElements = sizeof(inputElement)/sizeof(inputElement[0]);
    pd3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(inputElement ,numElements,g_pVertexShaderBuffer->GetBufferPointer(),g_pVertexShaderBuffer->GetBufferSize(),&g_pInputLayout);
    SAFE_RELEASE(g_pVertexShaderBuffer);
    SAFE_RELEASE(g_pPixelShaderBuffer);

    Vertex vertexData[3];
    vertexData[0].pos=XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    vertexData[1].pos=XMFLOAT3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
    vertexData[2].pos=XMFLOAT3( -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f );

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC desc;
    ZeroMemory(&desc,sizeof(desc));
    desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * 3;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    desc.MiscFlags = 0;
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA dataPointer;
    ZeroMemory(&dataPointer,sizeof(dataPointer));
    dataPointer.pSysMem = vertexData;
    pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&desc,&dataPointer,&g_pVertexBuffer);
    UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    UINT offset = 0;
    pd3dImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0,1,&g_pVertexBuffer,&stride,&offset);
    pd3dImmediateContext->IASetInputLayout(g_pInputLayout);
    pd3dImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
    return 0;
}

void CALLBACK onRender( ID3D11Device* pd3dDevice, ID3D11DeviceContext* pd3dImmediateContext, double fTime, float fElapsedTime, void* pUserContext )
{
    float ClearColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.25f, 0.25f, 0.55f };
    ID3D11RenderTargetView* pRTV = DXUTGetD3D11RenderTargetView();
    pd3dImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView( pRTV, ClearColor );
    pd3dImmediateContext->Draw(3,0);
}

void CALLBACK onDestroyed( void* pUserContext )
{
    SAFE_RELEASE(g_pIndexBuffer);
    SAFE_RELEASE(g_pVertexBuffer);
    SAFE_RELEASE(g_pInputLayout);
    SAFE_RELEASE(g_pPixelShader);
    SAFE_RELEASE(g_pVertexShader);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine,int nShowCmd)
{

    DXUTSetCallbackD3D11DeviceAcceptable( IsD3D11DeviceAcceptable );
    DXUTSetCallbackD3D11DeviceCreated(onDeviceCreated);
    DXUTSetCallbackD3D11FrameRender(onRender);
    DXUTSetCallbackD3D11DeviceDestroyed(onDestroyed);

    DXUTInit();
    DXUTCreateWindow(L"SMD",hInstance);
    DXUTCreateDevice(D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,true,300,300);
    DXUTMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

hopes there's someone have the patience to read all this long code -_-
and my shader code :

```
float4 VS( float4 Pos : POSITION ) : SV_POSITION
{
    return Pos;
}
float4 PS( float4 Pos : SV_POSITION ) : SV_Target
{
    return float4( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );    // Yellow, with Alpha = 1
}
```

the program alone runs well but when I tried to use PIX to trace it, it crashed and returned the following infomation:

```
.PRE: <this=0x06736580>ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 24, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x06736580> ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 24, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x06736580>ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 25, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x06736580> ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 25, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x06736580>ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 26, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x06736580> ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 26, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x06736580>ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 27, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x06736580> ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 27, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x06736580>ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 28, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x06736580> ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 28, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x06736580>ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 29, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x06736580> ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 29, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x06736580>ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 30, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x06736580> ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 30, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x06736580>ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 31, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x06736580> ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 31, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x06736580>ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 32, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x06736580> ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 32, 0x008DE4FC)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x06736580>ID3D11Device::Release()
Frame 000001 ........POST: <1><this=0x06736580> ID3D11Device::Release()
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x067ffa30>ID3D11DeviceContext::Release()
Frame 000001 ............PRE: RemoveObject(D3D11 Device Context, 0x067FFA30, 0x00C5F11C)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <> RemoveObject(D3D11 Device Context, 0x067FFA30, 0x00C5F11C)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: RemoveObject(D3D11 Device, 0x06736580, 0x00C3F384)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <> RemoveObject(D3D11 Device, 0x06736580, 0x00C3F384)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: RemoveObject(DXGI Device, 0x0672AC80, 0x00C3F07C)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <> RemoveObject(DXGI Device, 0x0672AC80, 0x00C3F07C)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: RemoveObject(DXGI Adapter, 0x06736B40, 0x07651C68)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <> RemoveObject(DXGI Adapter, 0x06736B40, 0x07651C68)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: RemoveObject(DXGI Factory, 0x06729D08, 0x00C31828)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <> RemoveObject(DXGI Factory, 0x06729D08, 0x00C31828)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <0><this=0x067ffa30> ID3D11DeviceContext::Release()
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x06775320>IDXGIFactory::EnumAdapters(2, 0x008DEA44)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND><this=0x06775320> IDXGIFactory::EnumAdapters(2, 0x008DEA44)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: D3DPERF_EndEvent()
Frame 000001 ........POST: <-1> D3DPERF_EndEvent()
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x0678df30>IDXGIOutput::GetDesc(0x008DEB20)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x0678df30> IDXGIOutput::GetDesc(0x008DEB20)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x0678df30>IDXGIOutput::GetDesc(0x008DEB20)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x0678df30> IDXGIOutput::GetDesc(0x008DEB20)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x0678df30>IDXGIOutput::GetDesc(0x008DEB20)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x0678df30> IDXGIOutput::GetDesc(0x008DEB20)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x0678df30>IDXGIOutput::GetDesc(0x008DEB20)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x0678df30> IDXGIOutput::GetDesc(0x008DEB20)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x0678df30>IDXGIOutput::GetDesc(0x008DEB20)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x0678df30> IDXGIOutput::GetDesc(0x008DEB20)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x0678df30>IDXGIOutput::GetDesc(0x008DEB20)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x0678df30> IDXGIOutput::GetDesc(0x008DEB20)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x06775320>IDXGIFactory::MakeWindowAssociation(0x005305E0, 0)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x06775320> IDXGIFactory::MakeWindowAssociation(0x005305E0, 0)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x06775320>IDXGIFactory::EnumAdapters1(0, 0x008DEE18)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(DXGI Adapter, 0x067368D8, 0x07651C68)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(DXGI Adapter, 0x067368D8, 0x07651C68)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x06775320> IDXGIFactory::EnumAdapters1(0, 0x008DEE18)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: D3D11CreateDevice(0x067368D8, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN, NULL, 2, 0x00A21AA4, 1, 7, 0x008DEE60, 0x008DEE48, 0x008DEE54)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(D3D11 Device, 0x0672AB00, 0x00C3D4D4)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(D3D11 Device, 0x0672AB00, 0x00C3D4D4)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(DXGI Device, 0x0672A6E0, 0x00C3D4D0)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(DXGI Device, 0x0672A6E0, 0x00C3D4D0)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(D3D11 Device Context, 0x06807880, 0x075C6800)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(D3D11 Device Context, 0x06807880, 0x075C6800)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK> D3D11CreateDevice(0x067368D8, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN, NULL, 2, 0x00A21AA4, 1, 7, 0x008DEE60, 0x008DEE48, 0x008DEE54)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x0672ab00>ID3D11Device::QueryInterface(IID_IDXGIDevice1, 0x008DEE00)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x0672ab00> ID3D11Device::QueryInterface(IID_IDXGIDevice1, 0x008DEE00)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x0672a6e0>IDXGIDevice::Release()
Frame 000001 ........POST: <2><this=0x0672a6e0> IDXGIDevice::Release()
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x0672ab00>ID3D11Device::CreateRasterizerState(0x008DEDC4, 0x008DEDB8)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(D3D11 Rasterizer State, 0x0672B350, 0x00C14DD4)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(D3D11 Rasterizer State, 0x0672B350, 0x00C14DD4)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x0672ab00> ID3D11Device::CreateRasterizerState(0x008DEDC4, 0x008DEDB8)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x0672b350>ID3D11RasterizerState::SetPrivateData({0x429b8c22, 0x9188, 0x4b0c, 0x87, 0x42, 0xac, 0xb0, 0xbf, 0x85, 0xc2, 0x00}, 12, 0x01114E74)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x0672b350> ID3D11RasterizerState::SetPrivateData({0x429b8c22, 0x9188, 0x4b0c, 0x87, 0x42, 0xac, 0xb0, 0xbf, 0x85, 0xc2, 0x00}, 12, 0x01114E74)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x06807880>ID3D11DeviceContext::RSSetState(0x0672B350)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <><this=0x06807880> ID3D11DeviceContext::RSSetState(0x0672B350)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x067368d8>IDXGIAdapter::EnumOutputs(0, 0x008DED94)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(DXGI Output, 0x06736A90, 0x0764B090)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(DXGI Output, 0x06736A90, 0x0764B090)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x067368d8> IDXGIAdapter::EnumOutputs(0, 0x008DED94)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x06736a90>IDXGIOutput::Release()
Frame 000001 ............PRE: RemoveObject(DXGI Output, 0x06736A90, 0x0764B090)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <> RemoveObject(DXGI Output, 0x06736A90, 0x0764B090)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <0><this=0x06736a90> IDXGIOutput::Release()
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x067368d8>IDXGIAdapter::EnumOutputs(1, 0x008DED94)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND><this=0x067368d8> IDXGIAdapter::EnumOutputs(1, 0x008DED94)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x067368d8>IDXGIAdapter::EnumOutputs(0, 0x00A21BD0)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(DXGI Output, 0x06736E00, 0x0764B090)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(DXGI Output, 0x06736E00, 0x0764B090)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x067368d8> IDXGIAdapter::EnumOutputs(0, 0x00A21BD0)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x06775320>IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain(0x0672AB00, 0x00A21A54, 0x008DEE3C)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(DXGI Swap Chain, 0x0672B3C8, 0x00C3F048)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(DXGI Swap Chain, 0x0672B3C8, 0x00C3F048)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(DXGI Surface, 0x0672ACE0, 0x074C4D80)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(DXGI Surface, 0x0672ACE0, 0x074C4D80)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(D3D10 Texture2D, 0x067755C0, 0x074C4D28)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(D3D10 Texture2D, 0x067755C0, 0x074C4D28)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x06775320> IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain(0x0672AB00, 0x00A21A54, 0x008DEE3C)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x0672b3c8>IDXGISwapChain::GetBuffer(0, IID_ID3D11Texture2D, 0x008DEC2C)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x0672b3c8> IDXGISwapChain::GetBuffer(0, IID_ID3D11Texture2D, 0x008DEC2C)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x067755c0>ID3D10Texture2D::Map(9300960, Unknown D3D10_MAP, 9301104, NULL)
D3D11 CORRUPTION: ID3D10Texture2D::Map: Fourth parameter is corrupt or NULL. [ MISCELLANEOUS CORRUPTION #16: CORRUPTED_PARAMETER4]
An unhandled exception occurred.
```

Comment: Just a suggestion as I don't have time for a full read of the code - is your winding order correct? Try swapping two vertices.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but I've tried that and noting new happens...

Comment: Have you got debugging enabled on the runtime? You might get a helpful error in the debug output if you do.

Comment: all DX functions returned S_OK....I've tried to use PIX to trace the program, but when PIX started it, it crashed. but it alone runs well with & whthout VisualStudio

Comment: Try making `Pos` a `float3` in your vertex shader and return `float4(Pos, 1);`.

Comment: thanks @Lucius , that has been tried too~,nothing new happened,and I also tried using XMFloat4 and DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT , problem still exists

Comment: It's just that I think your vertex shader would output default `0` for you vertices' `w` component. Even if it does not change anything right now I would still explicitly output `1`, just to be sure. Also, where are you binding the render target view to the output merger? Where do you set the viewport?

Comment: I think DXUT has done that for me , so I didn't do that.  I'll give it a shot

Comment: @Lucius: I added DXUT11's code into my project and found that DXUT had done binding renderTargetView and setting viewport in a function named "DXUTCreate3DEnvironment11", I debugged the project and the function was called, binding target view and setting viewport , and returned S_OK

Comment: If everything else fails I always load a working triangle sample from the web and replace it paragraph by paragraph with my own code, building and running the application after each replacement. If it does not draw at some point, you have found an error. If there is still sample code in the application at the end and it cannot be removed without breaking it, that code is what was missing. Good luck!

Comment: @Lucius:thanks, actually there is no such a sample using DXUT11 to draw a simple triangle -_-. (no matter how simple it sounds like ). I'll try rewriting the program to see if it works, thanks a lot~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved,thanks everyone~

I cleared Z buffer and stencil buffer in "onRender" Function, and the triangle finally appeared!!!
the Tutorial 03 in DX SDK June 2010 using DirectX11 doesn't cleared Z buffer in "onFrameRender" but it has no problem displaying the triangle. Maybe there's some detail I missed

Comment: Yes - it's not until Tutorial 05 that they add a depth buffer. :)